# iOS: UITableView first cell content with different type is not displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an `UITableView` in my `UIViewController`. The first cell has `type1` and the others `type2`.  My problem is that the content of my first cell is never displayed. 
This is my code:

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0) {
            return 240;
        }
        return 90;
    }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        Type1Cell * tmpCell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"type1Cell"];

        if (tmpCell1 == nil) {
            tmpCell1 = [[Type1Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"type1Cell"];
        }

        //set data
        return tmpCell1;

    } else {


    Type2Cell * tmpCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"type2Cell"];

    if (tmpCell == nil) {
        tmpCell = [[Type2Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"type2Cell"];
    }
   //set data

    return tmpCell;
    }


}
```

The first cell has the same specified height, but it's always blank. I don't have this problem with the other cells.

Comment: check identifier of firstcell in xib or prototype cell

Comment: @KKRocks it's the same as what I put in the code

Comment: check whether did you set hidden to contentView or anyother mistakenly.

Comment: @DSDharma OMG thank you so much! The view that is inside the `Content View` was set to hidden! I don't know how! Thank you! Can you please make it as an answer so anyone else running in the same issu can have some help?

Comment: @Llg glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure Cell content View or any-other mistakenly checked `Hidden` property to TRUE.

Answer (score -1):

You need to register your cell as well.

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"Type1Cell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"type1Cell"];
```

Comment: I don't use `Xib`, I use storyboard

Comment: Thank you I have found the problem: a view was set to `hidden` and I don't know how ! (I know it's a stupid mistake). Thank you again!

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not me :)